# Characteristic equations of Cauchy Problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I am trying to Solve a Cauchy Problem Given by

> $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial x}=0\;\;with \;\;u(x,0)=u_0(x)\;\;where \;\;x\in \mathbb{R}$$

The Auxiliary  equation is $$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$

so from this one Characteristic equation is given by $u=c_1$. But i can't figure out the second one

Please help

Thankyou.

Comment: $u = c_{1}$ implies $$\frac{dx}{c_{1}} = dt \implies x = c_{1} t + c_{2} \implies c_{2} = x - c_{1}t = x - ut$$ then remember that $c_{1} = f(c_{2})$

Comment: you should put this in answer.